# Query returns only one row

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a project in ASPX, and now I have to update, solve some problems. My knowledge of that language is not very high.. (But i have experience with other languages).

I'm trying to get a Gridview with the results (and understand the code)...

```
<asp:GridView ID="dvExterneHulp" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateRows="False" 
        GridLines="None"
        AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="odd" 
        AllowPaging="true" 
        CssClass="mGrid niceTable"
        OnDataBound="dvExterneHulp_DataBound" 
        PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" 
        OnPageIndexChanged="gv_PageIndexChanging">
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="odd"></AlternatingRowStyle>
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HulpverlenerNaam" HeaderText="Naam hulpverlener" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HulpverlenerAdres" HeaderText="Adres hulpverlener" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Uitleg">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("Uitleg").ToString().Replace("\n", "<br />") %>'
                    Style="word-break: normal; word-wrap: normal;">
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DatumBegin" HeaderText="Begindatum" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="klas_id" HeaderText="Klas" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DatumEind" HeaderText="Einddatum" />
    </Columns>
    <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr" />
</asp:GridView>
```

gv_PageIndexchanging

```
protected void gv_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView gv = (GridView)sender;
    gv.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    gv.DataBind();
}
```

Eh get results

```
eh = ehs.getLatestData(id, menuitem.Value).FirstOrDefault();
public IQueryable<externehulp> getLatestData(int id, string type)
{
    try
    {
        queryExterne =
            from eh in db.t_eh
            from teh in db.types_eh
            from k in db.klas
            where eh.type_eh == teh.Id
                  && teh.Naam == type
                  && eh.id == id
                  && eh.Klas_id == k.Id
            orderby eh.dateStart, eh.comments descending
            select eh;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
    return queryExterne;
}
```

Externehulp is a model with some variables..

Databoundcode

```
protected void dvExterneHulp_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Empty for the moment 
}
```

But i'm getting an error, and i can't find any meaning of it..
no overload for `gv_PageIndexChanging` matches delegate `System.EventHandler`

The strange thing is, I use the gv_PageIndexChanging on other gridviews, and that works fine.

What does the error mean? And maybe, how can I probably solve it?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onpageindexchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx `protected virtual void OnPageIndexChanged(
 EventArgs e
)`

Comment: You have to take look at both `OnPageIndexChanged` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onpageindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx and `OnPageIndexChanging` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pageindexchanging%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I made a mistake :)..

Autocomplete added indexchanged instead of changing ;). Thank you very mutch!

Now i have to try to fill that gridview with data..